# String truncation in Boost format

Tags: c++, string

- I have this code which I am using to print the current date. However when I print it the string is truncated and I cannot figure out why?

  - So as opposed to getting "**20-5 22-1-23**" I get "**20-5 22**" only.

I think some truncation is happening but I cannot figure out why.

```
using namespace std; 
    const boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

    const boost::format f = boost::format("%d-%d %ld-%ld-%ld")
            % now.date().year_month_day().day.as_number()
            % now.date().year_month_day().month.as_number()
            //% now.date().year_month_day().year.as_number()
            % now.time_of_day().hours()
            % now.time_of_day().minutes()
            % now.time_of_day().seconds();

    const string result = f.str();
    snprintf(ret, sizeof(result.c_str()), "%s",  result.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

[snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) has following signature:

```
int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );
```

where n is `Maximum number of bytes to be used in the buffer.` But you provide:

```
sizeof(result.c_str())
```

which has size of 4 bytes on 32bit architecture and 8 on 4 bit. You should provide here size of your buffer: `ret`.

Also that is why you get 7 chars in `"20-5 22"`, the eight is `\0`